# Why does vector asset crashes in android studio application?

Tags: java, android, mobile, crash

When I include vector asset in my code an application crashes with text vector has stopped. I wasnt to simply show the ventor on my screen and later change it with onClick metod to another vector.

I tried to include a android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  in build.gradle module but it didnt help. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code that i used in my application.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.vector;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnChange;
    ImageView ivAndroid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnChange.findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
        ivAndroid.findViewById(R.id.ivAndroid);



    }
}
```

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAndroid"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="157dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Change" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
and the error message


Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vector, PID: 27072
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vector/com.example.vector.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Button.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Button.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```